# Good Data Structure book to improve programming logic for children

Tags: data-structures, programming-logic

My cousin (Age 10) who studies in Standard 5. He wants to learn programming and programming logic.

Which book or resources should I refer? Is there any Good Data Structure book to improve programming logic specially for children?

Comment: There are numerous questions on this topic already asked - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=teach+programming+kids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu).  My kids learned about programming from it and one of them even made a science fair project from it.

From their About page:

> Scratch is a programming language that makes it easy to create your own interactive stories, animations, games, music, and art -- and share your creations on the web.
>   As young people create and share Scratch projects, they learn important mathematical and computational ideas, while also learning to think creatively, reason systematically, and work collaboratively.